# What method throws "You must like the page"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm doing my first steps in FB Apps using the [Javascript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) but I stumble upon this [Top Gear](http://www.facebook.com/topgear?sk=app_178048992237628) page and I would like to know what method throws this message as I had to make a `if` statement in `php` that would use the

```
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
```

from the [PHP Library](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) (really would love to do all in Javascript, really) to show a `<fb:like>` button and then subscribe up to the `edge.create` event in order to show the app it self...

I think was to much trouble if I could at least perform this technique as a simple call.

[image]

Comment: Just so you know: some people, including me, won't agree to that requirement, and will simply ignore the page. There is a big difference between being willing to provide some random site with opinion data, and being willing to prostitute one's reputation amongst ones' friends to promote a random site.

Comment: It's a client request to only show the app if the user likes it or not, I'm just the developer, I don't do the rules! **BTW** the app I did is for a non profit associate that takes care of child's without any support whatsoever, I don't do *bad* stuff ;) - I don't even need permissions for anything, it sends to friends and posts the wall without permissions.

Comment: I thought that SO was for helping people, not judge them!

Comment: Yeah, fair point, @balexandre. Sorry. My initial comment was intended as a warning in case you didn't realise that the rule may cause you to lose some of your feedback. If I had a clue how to actually solve your problem, rest assured I would have provided that as an answer too.

Comment: @balexandre, telling you that the feature you are implementing isn't user friendly is helping people (including you). Even if talking about prostitution an Nuremberg might not be the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/) has what you are looking for. Facebook will send post variables to your page with anonymous info about the user including their language and whether they are a fan or not.  Once they like the page, the page will refresh and you will know that they are a fan, so you won't need to subscribe to edge.create methods.  You will have a variable server side that indicates whether they are a fan and you can code from there.

Comment: what they specify in that article is using the PHP API, I would like to only use the javascript API... that was the point of my question.

Comment: Yeah - you can only get that information accessing the post variables which are unavailable from client side javascript.  That page is doing the same thing, they are decoding the post server side and sending that variable to javascript to decide whether or not to show the dialog.

Comment: thought that could be a FB dialog ... it seams a FB-alike dialog then... Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Look at their source code - they are creating those dialogs themselves with jquery.